# How can I make an MySQL View for Tax per Order

Tags: mysql, view, transpose, tax

My data:

[image: Table]
How can I get there? I tried to make a MySQL view on my table TAX.

CREATE VIEW TaxSplitPerOrder AS
    SELECT
        `OrderNumber`, `tax_invoiced`, `total_invoiced`, `created_at`, `tax_percent`, SUM(`tax_invoiced_order_item`)
    FROM
        test
    GROUP by OrderNumber;

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include all of the other non-summarized columns from your `SELECT` in the `GROUP BY` clause. You may want to sum `total_invoiced` too or else you will still have 2 rows for each order number.

Comment: SELECT `OrderNumber`, `tax_invoiced`, `total_invoiced`, `created_at`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN `tax_percent` = 21 THEN `tax_invoiced_order_item` END) `tax_21`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN `tax_percent` = 6 THEN `tax_invoiced_order_item` END) `tax_6`
FROM test
GROUP BY OrderNumber;

Answer (score 0):

The query:

SELECT `OrderNumber`, `tax_invoiced`, `total_invoiced`, `created_at`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN `tax_percent` = 21 THEN `tax_invoiced_order_item` END) `tax_21`,
       MAX(CASE WHEN `tax_percent` = 6 THEN `tax_invoiced_order_item` END) `tax_6`
FROM test
GROUP BY OrderNumber;